# How to move content to next item when current item have exeption overflowed by x pixels on the bottom in flutter listview [flutter]

Tags: flutter, listview, overflow, truncate

I showing content use listview.builder, if chapterInfo.bodyChunk have content large than height device then loss. how to check if content large than height device then move content to next item. Please help me! Thanks

```
ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
                              controller: _scrollController,
                              itemCount: chapterInfo.bodyChunk.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                        child: Html(
                                          data: chapterInfo.bodyChunk[index]
                                              .replaceAll("\n", "")
                                              .trim(),
                                          style: {
                                            '#': Style(
                                              textAlign: tempIsLeftAlign!
                                                  ? TextAlign.justify
                                                  : TextAlign.left,
                                              fontFamily: tempFontFamily,
                                              fontSize: FontSize(tempFontSize!),
                                              color: tempFontColor,
                                              backgroundColor: tempBackground,
                                            ),
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              })
```

[image: when font size 12 ( content show full )]
[image: when font size 16 (content loss *red circle)]

Comment: You say you have an exception because of overflowed pixels. Is that really true? Like, does it say that in the console? Because I'm not sure that this is the case. To me it just looks like you positioned the bottom bar over the content instead of below the content

Comment: sorry! it not show exeption overflowed, because i use expand widget. but if i hide bottom bar Content will still be lost.

Comment: what do you mean by move content to next item? describe the ideal situation when your issue is fixed